# Using apply and multi argument functions

Tags: r

I want to apply a function over a data frame.  The function takes V1 as arg1 and V2 as arg2 and I want to write the result to V3 or some other vector.

Is there an easy and compact way to do this?  I've posted a (non-working) example below.

Thanks

Stu

```
my.func <- function(X, Y) {
  return(X + Y)
} 
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,6)
my.df <- data.frame(a, b)
apply(my.df, 1, my.func, X="a", Y="b")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mapply()` is made for this.

Either of the following will do the job. The advantage of the second approach is that it scales nicely to functions that take an arbitrary number of arguments.

```
mapply(my.func, my.df[,1], my.df[,2])
# [1] 5 7 9

do.call(mapply, c(FUN=list(my.func), unname(my.df)))
# [1] 5 7 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel this would be better approached using `with` than `mapply` if you're calling elements inside a `data.frame`:

```
with(my.df,my.func(X=a,Y=b))
#[1] 5 7 9
```

It's still quite a clean method even if you need to do the explicit conversion from a matrix:

```
with(data.frame(my.mat),my.func(X=a,Y=b))
#[1] 5 7 9
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really any need for an `*apply` function here. Vectorization would suffice:

```
my.df$c <- my.df$a + my.df$b
#  a b c
#1 1 4 5
#2 2 5 7
#3 3 6 9
```

Your `apply` solution can't work the way you have written it because `apply` does not pass a named vector through to your function: e.g.

```
colnames(my.df)
#[1] "a" "b"

apply( my.df , 1 , colnames )
#NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I just posted the sum example as a simple  representation of a function expecting 2 args, obviously if I wanted to sum the 2 cols I would just use your example.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @stu np. I thought it was just a toy example. The point here is that `apply` doesn't pass the name of columns to the function it applies so you can't use it that way (but it does seem to pass attributes though - if you try `apply( my.df , 1 , attributes )`.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, `rowSums(my.df)` will do the job.  For more complicated tasks, you can use the `mapply` function.  For example: `mapply(my.func, my.df[a], my.df[b])`.

Alternatively, you could rewrite your function to take a vector argument:

```
my.otherfunc <- function(x) sum(x)
apply(my.df, 1, my.otherfunc)
```

It's important to understand that when `apply` feeds each row or column into the function, it's sending *one* vector, not a list of separate entries.  So you should give it a function with a single (vector) argument.